# Custom Icon For UITextView in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I want to create a `UITextView` (or `UITextField`) with custom icon.

I know how to add a `UIImageView` to the `UITextView` but the cursor ignore the UIImageView and I cant edit or delete the icon (the `UIImageView`).

What is the best way to do it?
I know that it is possible because apple use it in the iMessage (image attached) and there is another application name "kik" with the same behavior.

[image]

Comment: u cant pass image in textfield... currently keyboard extension can only pass a plain NSString to the host app. Some people use NSPasteboard to exchange data, but that needs the host app to do the “paste".

Comment: agree with @Helix, you cannot. What "kik" did is, use separate view above `UITextField` to insert the image if you observe carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this gever ;) :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"before after"];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"];

CGFloat oldWidth = textAttachment.image.size.width;

CGFloat scaleFactor = oldWidth / (self.textField.frame.size.width - 10);
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(6, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
self.textField.attributedText = attributedString;
```